# AWK script- Not showing data

Tags: variables, awk, scripting

I'm trying to create a variable to sum columns 26 to 30 and 32.
SO far I have this code which prints me the hearder and the output format like I want but no data is being shown.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }
NR>1 {
    TotalPositiveStats= ($26+$27+$28+$29+$30+$32)
    }
        {printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s\n",
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,TotalPositiveStats
        }

NR==1   {
    print "EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,HOme,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,TotalPositiveStats" }#header
```

Input data:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
```

Output expected:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,TotalPositiveStats
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5,35
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4,34
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9,54
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7,38
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2,29
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9,36
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3,51
```

This script will be called like `gawk -f script.awk <filename>`.

Currently when calling this is the output (It seems to be calculating the variable but the rest of fields are empty)
[image]

Comment: if you're *not allowed* to use `awk` and must instead use `bash` then it sounds like this is some sort of classroom assignment which in turn means you've probably covered `bash/looping` constructs recently in class in which case you should be able to show your coding efforts

Comment: also keep in mind that `bash` can only do integer math so you'll likely need to pull something else (eg, `bc`) into the mix to handle float/real values; are there additional limitations on what can and cannot be used (eg, is `bc` allowed)?

Comment: I better prefer not to comment on the theory given by the teacher... We have not touched loops at this level, only for printing info at command line level. :( believe me this is my last option, I would prefer to find the solution by myself but I don't seem to be grasping the column management logic (I come from python, where all is rainbows)

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, there are no float on those columns ! :) only int

Comment: "I tried searching but not a single for loop inserts values again as new column". That's because mutating a file as you iterate through it is a terrible idea.  Don't do it.  Filter the output and create a new file.  When you are done, rename the new file so it has the original name.  Any other approach is courting disaster.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell. Let's be clear, I need to do an iterative structure with a csv file but keeping the format for later usage. All the loops I know are counters or to get a number as a result. I need to perform some kind of operation with a loop (I've been given free choice) but I sincerely just don't know what could I do! I only can think of creating a new column or filtering with a loop.... Any other solution that implies that the output has other format than the original is not valid, because I need all the others columns for later.

Comment: That's why I thougth of adding multiple columns and creating a new one. If I can do something easier such as filtering out given a condition, I'm good. The teacher has not explained anything similiar and now I'm completely lost.

Comment: I suggest you examine the `read` command. You can put that into a `while` loop and have the entire `while` loop take its STDIN from the original file. As you read each line of the original file, perform your calculations and write the output to a temporary working file. Then, when the loop is complete, as William suggests, over-write the original file with the working file.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is well suited to summing columns:

```
awk 'NR>1{$(NF+1)=$26+$27+$28+$29+$30+$32}1' FS=, OFS=, input-file > tmp
mv tmp input-file
```

That doesn't add a field in the header line, so you might want something like:

```
awk '{$(NF+1) = NR>1 ? ($26+$27+$28+$29+$30+$32) : "TotalPositiveStats"}1' FS=, OFS=,
```

Comment: Hi William. One general question. I understand all these answers are "one liner" answer to be used in the command line. But the way I'm learning bash, awk, sed.... are with scripts. How I¡m supposed to adapt these one liners so that the script works? Because I see people tend to just use one liners instead of scripts, and I want to be able to do more than just one thing. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine I will need to put a BEGIN {FS= ","} {OFS=","}... but I am confused as to how to do this structure change

Comment: You don't need to use a BEGIN block, but you can.  You can copy the one-liners verbatim into your script.

Comment: Hello @William Pursell, I have written a script and updated the question. Could you take a look to see what could be not working? Thanks

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias You need to print each line instead of waiting to try to print it all at the end.  If you are trying to accumulate a sum over all lines, you'll need a slightly different approach.

Comment: In the current state of the code, just change `END` to `NR == 1` and move the one printf into the other (the NR>1) block.

Comment: Hi, is not returning value in any field besides the one which is the variable. I've done the change as you told me

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias In its current state, the code you have in the question won't even run.  You need to rearrange some brackets.

Comment: Sorry it seems I have copy pasted the code without these brackets. As far as I know all block need to have a { and a }. Please see updated the code

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias There should be a total of two `{}`, not 3.  Move the printf into the first grouping.  You probably need to review a basic awk tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation on the issues with the current `printf` output is covered in the 2nd half of this answer (below).

It appears OP's objective is to reformat three of the current fields while also adding a new field on the end of each line. (**NOTE:** certain aspects of OPs code are not reflected in the expected output so I'm not 100% sure what OP is looking to generate; regardless, OP should be able to tweak the provided code to generate the desired result)

Using `sprintf()` to reformat the three fields we can rewrite OP's current code as:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 { print $0, "TotalPositiveStats"; next }
      { TotalPositiveStats = ($26+$27+$28+$29+$30+$32)
        $17 = sprintf("%.3f",$17)                        # FG_PCT
        if ($20 != "") $20 = sprintf("%.3f",$20)         # 3P_PCT
        $23 = sprintf("%.3f",$23)                        # FT_PCT
        print $0, TotalPositiveStats
      }
' raw.dat
```

**NOTE:** while OP's `printf` shows a format of `%.2f %` for the 3 fields of interest (`$17`, `$20`, `$23`), the expected output shows that the fields are not actually being reformatted (eg, `$17` remains `%.3f`, `$20` is an empty string, `$23` remains `%.2f`); I've opted to leave `$20` as blank otherwise reformat all 3 fields as `%.3f`; OP can modify the `sprintf()` calls as needed

This generates:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,TotalPositiveStats
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5,40
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1.000,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4,37
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9,57
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1.000,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7,44
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.750,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2,31
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9,41
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.750,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3,56
```

**NOTE:** in OP's expected output it appears the last/new field (`TotalPositiveStats`) does not contain the value from `$30` hence the mismatch between the expected results and this answer; again, OP can modify the assignment statement for `TotalPositiveStats` to include/exclude fields as needed

---

Regarding the issues with the current `printf` ...

```
{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%.2f %,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s\n",
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,TotalPositiveStats}
```

... is referencing (`awk`) variables that have not been defined (eg, `EndYear, Rk, G`). [**NOTE:** one exeception is the very last variable in the list - `TotalPositiveStats` - which has in fact been defined earlier in the script.]

The default value for undefined variables is the empty string (`""`) or zero (`0`), depending on how the `awk` code is referencing the variable, eg:

- `printf "%s", EndYear` => `EndYear` is treated as a string and the printed result is an empty string; with an output field delimiter of a comma (`,`) this empty strings shows up as 2 commas next to each other (`,,`)
- `printf "%.2f %", FG_PCT` => `FG_PCT` is treated as a numeric (because of the `%f` format) and the printed result is `0.00 %`

Where it gets a little interesting is when the (undefined) variable name starts with a numeric (eg, `3P`) in which case the `P` is ignored and the entire reference is treated as a number, eg:

- `printf "%s", 3P` => `3P` is processed as `3` and the printed result is `3`

This should explain the 5 static values (`0.00 %`, `3`, `3`, `3.00 %` and `0.00 %`) printed in all output lines as well as the 'missing' values between the rest of the commas (eg, `,,,,`).

Obviously the last value in the line is an actual number, ie, the value of the `awk` variable `TotalPositiveStats`.